# Joint density of a quadratic function of entries of orthogonal matrix

Tags: pr.probability, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, probability-distributions, special-functions, random-matrices

$U=(U_{ij})_{1\leq i,j\leq m},V=(V_{ij})_{1\leq i,j\leq m}$ are independently and uniformly distributed on the orthogonal group $O(m)$. For any positive integer $k,n$ such that $1\leq k\leq n\leq m$, define the following $k$ random variables：
$$X_i=\sum_{j=1}^nU_{ij}^2V_{ij}^2, i=1,2,...,k$$
Is it possible to write down the joint density of $(X_1,...,X_k)$ with respect to the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^k$?

Answer (score 1):

There is no closed-form expression for arbitrary $m$, but for $m\gg 1$ the matrix elements $U_{ij}$ and $V_{ij}$ are independent Gaussians of zero mean and variance $1/m$. The probability distribution of $Z_{ij}=m^2 U_{ij}^2 V_{ij}^2$ is then given by a Bessel function,
$$P(Z_{ij})=\frac{1}{\pi\sqrt Z_{ij}}K_0(\sqrt Z_{ij}).$$
In this large-$m$ limit the variables 
$$X_i=m^{-2}\sum_{j=1}^n Z_{ij},\;\;i=1,2,\ldots k,$$
are all independent and the characteristic function $F_X(s)=\mathbb{E}[e^{-sm^2X_i}]$ of $m^2X_i$ is the $n$-th power of the characteristic function $F_Z(s)=\mathbb{E}[e^{-sZ_{ij}}]$ of $Z_{ij}$,
$$F_X(s)=\left(\frac{1}{2  \sqrt{\pi s}}\exp\left(\frac{1}{8 s}\right) K_0\left(\frac{1}{8 s}\right)\right)^n.$$

Comment: To use Gaussian approximation, we need the corresponding $U_{ij},V_{ij}$ be approximated by Gaussian simultaneously, right? However, this simultaneous Gaussian approximation does not hold if $k$ and $n$ are comparable to $m$, see https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aop/1158673325

Comment: certainly, you need to send $m$ to infinity at fixed $k,n$.